# FFmpeg - add an animated gif (cropped by mask) to the video

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, transparency, mask, alpha

I have 3 inputs:

1. Video file: https://file.io/6jtUlnZ7TGmT
2. Animated GIF with **transparent background** https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmJpw.gif
3. Mask file (BW) **the same resolution as the video** https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1MCY.png

I want to put the image on the video, but **throw out all GIF pixels** that are **transparent in the mask** (replace them with transparent ones).

[image: Video]
[image: Mask]
[image]
[image: Result]

My current command, without masking (it works fine):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i animation.gif \
-filter_complex "[1]scale=700x700[scaled_gif];\
[0][scaled_gif]overlay=50:30:shortest=1" \
-codec:a copy output.mp4
```

**UPDATE #1**

I managed to get closer to my goal with this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -i mask.png \ 
-filter_complex "[1:v]alphaextract[mask]; \
movie=animation.gif,scale=1920x1080[scaled_gif]; \
[scaled_gif][mask]alphamerge[masked]; \
[0:v][masked]overlay=0:0" \
-c:a copy output_masked.mp4
```

but it has 2 problems:

1. GIF loses it's transparency. Transparent pixels become white.
2. GIF plays only once (i.e. no loop)

Output: https://file.re/2021/03/11/outputmasked/

Comment: If you make your mask black and white instead of black and transparent it will result in a simpler ffmpeg command.

Comment: @llogan thank you, you're right! BW mask is better. I've done with masking, but now GIF loses it's transparency (see UPDATE #1 above)

Comment: Can you provide a link to your GIF?

Comment: @llogan sure, here two examples: https://i.imgur.com/Vo3KHZm.gif and https://i.imgur.com/btgHQPm.gif

Comment: @llogan this is an output I'm getting now with the second GIF file https://file.re/2021/03/11/outputmasked/, the alpha channel of the GIF turns white color.